What am I doing wrong trying to create MQTTS connection to Azure IoTHub with SIM7670G modem
I am trying to use a T-SIM7670G S3 from LilyGo (https://www.lilygo.cc/products/t-sim-7670g-s3) to connect to an Azure IoTHub, using AT modem commands. I am unable to start the MQTT service, even though the PDP is up, time is set, and I have an IP address. It seems to me that the SSL connection succeeds also, but still the AT+CMQTTSTART command fails.
Can anyone spot where I did something wrong, or missed a step? Any help is appreciated.
The commands I use are as follows (log output):

Manufacturer: SIMCOM INCORPORATED
Model: SIM7670G-MNGV
Revision: V1.9.01
OK

ATI Manufacturer: SIMCOM INCORPORATED Model: SIM7670G-MNGV Revision: V1.9.01 IMEI: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
IMSI: AT+CIMI
AT+CIMI
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
OK

AT+CPIN?
+CPIN: READY
OK

AT+CREG?
+CREG: 0,5
OK

AT+CEREG?
+CEREG: 0,5
OK

AT+CPSI?
+CPSI: LTE,Online,238-01,0xD48,5314856,394,EUTRAN-BAND7,2850,5,5,-11,-109,-97,14
OK

AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","TM"
OK

AT+CGACT=1,1
OK

AT+CGACT?
+CGACT: 1,1
OK

AT+CTZU=1
OK

AT+CNTP="time.nist.gov",32
OK

AT+CCLK?
+CCLK: "24/08/16,12:04:25+08"
OK

AT+CREG?
+CREG: 0,5
OK

Registration status:
Network registration successful, currently in roaming mode

AT+CGPADDR=1
+CGPADDR: 1,10.59.245.255
OK

AT+CDNSCFG="8.8.8.8","8.8.4.4"
OK

Modem initialized
System time set to: Fri Aug 16 12:04:30 2024

Connecting to Azure

Uploading DigiCert Global Root G2
AT+CCERTDOWN=cacert.pem,1295
>-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDjjCCAnagAwIBAgIQAzrx5qcRqaC7KGSxHQn65TANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBh
MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMRkwFwYDVQQLExB3
...
8rGOmaFvE7FBcf6IKshPECBV1/MUReXgRPTqh5Uykw7+U0b6LJ3/iyK5S9kJRaTe
pLiaWN0bfVKfjllDiIGknibVb63dDcY3fe0Dkhvld1927jyNxF1WW6LZZm6zNTfl
MrY=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
OK

AT+CTCPKA=1,2,5,1
OK

AT+CCHSTART
ERROR

AT+CCHADDR
+CCHADDR: 10.59.245.255
OK

AT+CSSLCFG="ignorelocaltime",0,1
OK

AT+CSSLCFG="negotiatetime",0,25
OK

AT+CSSLCFG="sslversion",0,4
OK

AT+CSSLCFG="authmode",0,1
OK

AT+CSSLCFG="cacert",0,"cacert.pem"
OK

AT+CCHSET=1,1
ERROR

AT+CCHSSLCFG=0,0
OK

AT+CCHOPEN=0,"IOTHUB.azure-devices.net",8883,2
+CCHOPEN: 0,1
OK

AT+CCHSET?
+CCHSET: 1,1
OK

AT+CMQTTSTART
ERROR

AT+CMQTTACCQ=0,"DEVICE",1
ERROR

AT+CMQTTSSLCFG=0,0
OK

AT+CMQTTCONNECT=0,"ssl://IOTHUB.azure-devices.net:8883",60,1,"IOTHUB.azure-devices.net/DEVICE/?api-version=2018-06-30","SharedAccessSignature sr=IOTHUB.azure-devices.net%2Fdevices%2FDEVICE&sig=rc3c2K%2BHF0l%2Bu16lv0DEi6lXqgSqIqouVgRwkr2tKKU%3D&se=1723810204"
+CMQTTCONNECT: 0,12
ERROR

I expect the CMQTTSTART command to succeed, such that I can start subscribing and publishing to the MQTT topics required to interact with the IoTHub.

What sets the MQTT clientid?

@MarkRadbourne, the client id is set with this command:
AT+CMQTTACCQ=0,"DEVICE",1
where "DEVICE" must be the actual device id of the iot device, according to the Azure documentation.
However, before any MQTT commands the modem documentation from SIM states that CMQTTSTART must be executed before any other MQTT related commands. The problem is that it fails. This probably means that any other MQTT related command fails also.
The CMQTTSTART command also starts the PDP context. I already have an IP, so I guess the PDP works. Maybe there is a way to get the error reason?

Another thing:
AT+CCHSTART fails .. but later on the AT+CCHOPEN succeeds, and states that a SSL socket is open (+CCHOPEN: 0,1).
If I leave out the AT+CCHSTART, then the CCHOPEN does not succeed. So, something works, but there might also be some misconfiguration. But what?

What error do you get with extended error reporting enabled (AT+CMEE=2)?

@hlovdal unfortunately setting AT+CMEE=2 does not provide further information. Output is unchanged.

+CCHOPEN: 0,1 fails as well. Because 1 means error - Alerting state
